# calculator textBox convert to hex c#

Tags: string, textbox, hex, decimal, calculator

I have tried two options but both have failed and show decimal result

```
private void buttonHex_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            int hex = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = hex.ToString("X");
        }
```

and

```
 private void buttonHex_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            double hex = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            long l = (long)hex;
            textBox1.Text = "h " + Convert.ToString(l, 16);
        }
```

The second option works fine with binary, but doesnt want to convert to hex?! Please help